# Can I schedule a night restore/wipe? Or other management solution

Tags: restore, kiosk-mode

I (will shortly) have a small (5-10) android tablets for use in my school. I want them to automatically wipe clean at the end of each day (specifically, remove any user data, even more specifically, browsing history/downloads). I'd mostly likely have the devices locked down to just web browsing using [surelock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock) or similar.

How can I do this? Titanium backup doesn't seem to have a scheduled restore function.

Alternately, are there other management tools that would achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 3):

There are two products in market which i found awesome :)

[SureFox](http://www.42gears.com/surefox/surefoxandroid.html) :  Kiosk Mode browser for Android Smartphones and Tablet which restricts user to browse only selected Websites, Which has many more options inside Browser Preferences For eg. Private Browsing and many More. try exploring this.

[SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/surelockandroid.html) : You already Know about it ;)

You can try using [SureFox](http://www.42gears.com/surefox/surefoxandroid.html) on top of [SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/surelockandroid.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's possible to do a factory reset with it but I know that Tasker is a great tool to automate things. You can try it for free first.

Comment: I don't want a factory reset (I need to maintain certain settings eg wifi credentials). I use tasker on my phone, but haven't found a function that does this.

Comment: So you want to delete a set of files from the sdcard then? Try python for android for instance, you can shedule a python script from within Tasker

Comment: @hcpl I think python would be an overkill for this as it could be done in a few lines of shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds to me like you'd need to root the phones and write a `bash` script to execute the SD card wipe and the browser cache wipe.  If you don't know how to write scripts, [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) is a good place to ask for help (the primary Stack Exchange site).  [Script Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.tools.scriptmanager&hl=en) is a good app for managing your scripts and when they execute (on boot would probably make the most sense, especially if you use Tasker to shut the machine down every night on a schedule).

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the data and cache for each app one by one, from within the application settings, then wipe the sdcard.

But, if all you need to do in terms of setting up is a (short) wifi keys, then a factory reset might be best. It may be possible to bake your settings into the rom  e.g put your wifi keys in /system/etc/wifi/wifi_supplicant.conf . That example would allow wifi keys to survive a factory reset.

Any other solution I can think of would involve constantly (un)rooting , especially if you're talking about teenagers. Or, you could lock down root access with Superuser Elite  and if you were confident that nobody would be messing with adb, you might go that way.

There are "business solutions" out there, but that would be too much surely.